# How to override (vendor/magento/module-gift-card/Model/Plugin) Magento\GiftCard\Model\Plugin\QuoteItem afterConvert() function Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, catalog, gift-card

override a function (vendor/magento/module-gift-card/Model/Plugin) Magento\GiftCard\Model\Plugin\QuoteItem afterConvert() function Magento 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not add Plugin on Plugin if it is not necessary.

First, depending on what are the requirements then you can go for it to add Plugin on Plugin.

One way to change the functionality of a plugin is to disable it entirely and redefine a plugin for the same type but not a suitable way until it is fix for existing problems.

To disable a plugin, one can easily do it using the **disable** attribute like below.

**File: app/code/Custom/GiftCard/etc/di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\ToOrderItem">
    <!-- Check the name (append_gift_card_data_to_order) of the plugin from the vendor/magento/module-gift-card/etc/di.xml -->
    <plugin name="append_gift_card_data_to_order" disabled="true" />
</type>
```

Alternatively, you can give a try on below by adding plugin on the class `Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\ToOrderItem` instead of 
`Magento\GiftCard\Model\Plugin\QuoteItem`

**File: app/code/Custom/GiftCard/etc/di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\ToOrderItem">
        <plugin name="own_gc_append_gift_card_data_to_order" type="Custom\GiftCard\Plugin\QuoteItemPlugin" sortOrder="50"/>
</type>
```

Change the value of `sortOrder="50"` small if you want below plugin executed earlier and set larger `sortOrder` if you want a plugin to be called lately.

**File: app/code/Custom/GiftCard/Plugin/QuoteItemPlugin.php**

```
<?php


namespace Custom\GiftCard\Plugin;

use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\ToOrderItem as QuoteToOrderItem;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item as OrderItem;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\AbstractItem;
use Magento\GiftCard\Model\Giftcard;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;

class QuoteItemPlugin
{
    /**
     * Psr Logger  instance
     *
     * @var LoggerInterface
     * @since 100.1.0
     */
    protected $logger;


    /**
     * @param ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        LoggerInterface $logger
    )
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;

    }

    /**
     * @param QuoteToOrderItem $subject
     * @param OrderItem $orderItem
     * @param AbstractItem $quoteItem
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function afterConvert(QuoteToOrderItem $subject, OrderItem $orderItem, AbstractItem $quoteItem, $data = [])
    {
        /**
         * Add/change your logic here
         */
        $this->logger->debug('afterGenerateWorks: ');
        $this->logger->debug(__METHOD__ . ' - ' . __LINE__);
        if ($orderItem->getId()) {
            $this->logger->debug( $orderItem->getId() );
        }

        //Check return type as per Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item
        return $orderItem;
    }
}
```

[Click on this link for a detailed guide on Plugin on Plugin](https://www.czettner.com/magento/2018/06/16/how-to-override-plugin-interceptor.html)

Comment: This seems very useful , will check and let you know if its works as per requirement. Thanks sandip